# Why Visual Studio does not refresh some properties in its Property Window when they are modified in an other propery's setter?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, properties

Why Visual Studio does not refresh some properties in its Property Window when they are modified in an other property's setter?

Here is an example:

```
public partial class MyControl: UserControl {
  public MyControl() { InitializeComponent(); }
  private bool myThing=false;
  [Category("Behavior")]
  public bool Mything {
    get { return myThing; }
    set {
      myThing=value;
      Enabled=!Enabled;
      Visible=!Visible;
      AllowDrop=!AllowDrop;
      AutoScroll=!AutoScroll;
      AutoSize=!AutoSize;
      TabIndex+=2;
    }
  }
}
```

Make this class to Class Library, build it to a DLL, then put this component to Visual Studio's Toolbox.
Then make a new 'Windows Forms Application' in VS, and put this component(MyControl) from the toolbox to Form1.

Now go and change the Mything property in the VS-property-editor with clicks. As it turns on and off, you can see (in the property editor) it increases the TabIndex, and turns on and off the AutoSize and `AutoScroll` properties correctly, BUT NOT the Enabled, Visible, and AllowDrop properties!
These three does not change in the property editor!!
WHY?

You can try this out with a Button instead of a UserControl also, and you can see the Button changes to gray when Enabled property is turned off (by Mything-setter), BUT ONLY in the designer view, in the property editor window it still shows the original value!!
Furthermore if you save the application, you can see in the Form1.Designer.cs that the Enabled property is not refreshed!! And next time loading the project it loads the unmodified value! (which was shown in the property editor window)

I've tried using `RefreshProperties` Attribute, I've tried implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but no luck! :(

So, why Visual Studio does refresh some properties in its property-editor and DOES NOT refresh some other?
And (in the setter code) how can i FORCE Visual Studio property window to REFRESH?

Any ideas?